# RPG **FREE : What is the equivalent free-form declaration for a LIKE definition with a relative size

Tags: rpgle

```
DName+++++++++++ETDsFrom+++To/L+++IDc.Keywords+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Comments++++++++++++
DQty              S             11p 3 INZ(123.50)                                              
DQtyX             S             +1    LIKE(Qty)                                                
 *. 1 ...+... 2 ...+... 3 ...+... 4 ...+... 5 ...+... 6 ...+... 7 ...+... 8 ...+... 9 ...+... 0
```

How can standalone variables be declared and sized relatively in fully-free RPG?

Here I want to declare QtyX as 12p3

Comment: This question is perfectly clear to an RPGLE developer.

Comment: The answer [per the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=keywords-likename-length-adjustment) is `dcl-s QtyX like(Qty:1);`

Comment: typo, you need the `+` or `-` so  `dcl-s QtyX like(Qty:+1);`

Comment: It's tough to convince stackoverflow sometimes. Thank you @Charles for supporting this Q and helping with the exact solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [per the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=keywords-likename-length-adjustment) is

`dcl-s QtyX like(Qty:+1);`